# Where do I find a button "Lock Layers and Used Camera to Scene" in Blender 2.92.0?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

Where do I find a button "Lock Layers and Used Camera to Scene" (the lock icon in a 3D viewport) in Blender 2.92.0? Rendered Picture is not what active camera shows

Answer (score 1):

Used camera is right here in scene properties:

[image]

and if you tap the filter symbol here:

[image]

and then press the arrow (selectable)

[image]

you can then tap on the collections selectable icon (to lock the layer)

[image]